# Widget with custom text support

Tags: java, android, android-widget, widget

I have used custom text for widget but i know that widget can't support custom text mean TextView with our TTF file

So i have used below code for support

```
    @Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    ......................
    remoteViews.setTextColor(R.id.textViewGuj, settings.getInt(
                Const.Mean_Pref_Color_Key,
                context.getResources().getColor(R.color.orange)));
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textViewEng, engWord);
        remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.textViewGuj,
                buildUpdate(meaning));
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.LinearLayout01,
                pendingIntent1);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
    }
}


public Bitmap buildUpdate(String time) 
{
    Bitmap myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(50, 50, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
    Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas(myBitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Typeface clock = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(),"fonts/Gujarat.ttf");
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setSubpixelText(true);
    paint.setTypeface(clock);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(settings.getInt(
            Const.Mean_Pref_Color_Key,
            mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.orange)));
    //paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setTextSize(20);
    paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
    myCanvas.drawText(time, 80, 60, paint);
    return myBitmap;
}
```

and for update ImageView

```
    remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.textViewGuj,
                buildUpdate(meaning));
```

Now my problem is that my widget is showing me nothing it goes dark black nothing is shown in widget no any error is generating can any one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a problem in your below code

```
      remoteViews.setTextColor(R.id.textViewGuj, settings.getInt(
            Const.Mean_Pref_Color_Key,
            context.getResources().getColor(R.color.orange)));
```

just remove this line because you are using ImageView and there is no any TextColor Property for ImageView

Hope works fine  :)